# Unable to import _future_ in anaconda

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda

I am unable to `import _future_` in Anaconda. I am using Python 2.7:

```
Error:  from _future_ import absolute_import, division, print_function
ImportError: No module named _future_
```

Answer (score 3):

You are importing the package incorrectly.  It's `__future__` not `_future_` (it's using two underscores).

If you look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html) it is written on the first line.